# How to find unused classes generated by Lombok

Tags: java, lombok

How to find unused classes generated by Lombok, if Foo.builder() is not used or if the all arguments constructor is not used I would prefer to remove these annotations. But how can I find this in my code

```
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
class Foo {
}
```

Comment: You can remove those and try to compile the project. If compiles successfully, then that's OK. I'm not sure if you're asking for this help or not.

Comment: You need some IDE feature? If so, what IDE do you use?

Answer (score 0):

you can [delombok](https://projectlombok.org/features/delombok) your code.

For Intellij [Check here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/annotation-processors-support.html)

Next may be Sonar will also help you for some additional analysis to find used code